# Edit CSS after DOM completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, load

I have a navigation menu where it is entirely control by JavaScript.

But somehow I can't refer/target it using `$("#floatNavigation")`, it returns `undefined` when I try to perform a click/mouseover/log.

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should post some code.

Comment: use `$(document).ready(function() { /*ur stuff...*/ } )`

Comment: try wrapping your `$("#floatNavigation")` code into `$(window).load()`

Comment: You shall post both HTML and Javascript code in order for us to provide you with a proper answer. No code, no possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have jQuery wait until your page (technically, the DOM) is completely loaded. You can do this using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Anything in here will run when the DOM is completely loaded
    var floatNavigation = $("#floatNavigation");
});
```

You can read more about the `$(document).ready()` statement on [its respective jQuery documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: More succint is `$(function() { ... })`.

Comment: `Or jQuery(function($) { ... });`